# php - Accessing json array object

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a JSON array object in which I am trying to append an array to one of the fields.

```
{"email":"bar@foo.org","password":"password","devices":{}}

print_r($arr) gives me:

Array ( [0] => {
                "email":"bar@foo.org",
                "password":"password",
                "devices":{}
                } 
        [1] => {
                "email":"bar2@foo.org",
                "password":"password",
                "devices":{}
                }
    )
```

where $device_info is an array of structure:

```
array(
        "number" => $phoneNumber,
        "type" => "CellPhone",
        "config" => array(
            "batteryLevel" => 100,
            "Lowbatterylevel" => 10,
        )
```

I am trying to do this:

```
array_push($arr[$i]["devices"],$device_info);
```

which throws an error "Warning: Illegal string offset 'devices' "

I saw some other similar questions in StackOverflow but the solutions didn't work. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us your `json_decode()` statement

Comment: If you showed us the full detials of the `print_r($arr)` instead of a summary. the answer would be obvious

Comment: Actually I doubt that a `print_r()` with that initial string outputs an array...

Comment: @arkascha I am assuming he must have done one to get anything like the output he suggests

Comment: @RiggsFolly Looks to me like she confuses objects and arrays.

Comment: @arkascha Exactly

Comment: both of you are right. I had confused objects and arrays. I am able to do push the device information to the array now.

Answer (score 2):

You are not looking closely enough at your original JSON String or the full output from your `print_r()`

That is an Object containing properties and `devices` property is an object as well that contains it own properies

Here is some sample code to get your going

```
$s = '{"email":"bar@foo.org","password":"password","devices":{}}';

$j = json_decode($s);

$o = new stdClass();
$o->number = 999;
$o->type = "CellPhone";
$o->config = array("batteryLevel" => 100,"Lowbatterylevel" => 10);

$j->devices = $o;
print_r($j);
echo json_encode($j);
```

Results are

```
stdClass Object
(
    [email] => bar@foo.org
    [password] => password
    [devices] => stdClass Object
        (
            [number] => 999
            [type] => CellPhone
            [config] => Array
                (
                    [batteryLevel] => 100
                    [Lowbatterylevel] => 10
                )

        )

)
{"email":"bar@foo.org","password":"password","devices":{"number":999,"type":"CellPhone","config":{"batteryLevel":100,"Lowbatterylevel":10}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

To me this looks like you confuse objects and arrays in your approach...

That json encoded string you posted does *not* encode an array but an object. So you have to treat it as such. Take a look at this simple demonstration code:

```
<?php
$payload = [
    "number" => '01234567890',
    "type" => "CellPhone",
    "config" => [
        "batteryLevel" => 100,
        "Lowbatterylevel" => 10
    ]
];
$input = '{"email":"bar@foo.org","password":"password","devices":{}}';
$data = json_decode($input);
$data->devices = $payload;
$output = json_encode($data);
print_r(json_decode($output));
print_r($output);
```

The output ob above obviously is:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [email] => bar@foo.org
    [password] => password
    [devices] => stdClass Object
        (
            [number] => 01234567890
            [type] => CellPhone
            [config] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [batteryLevel] => 100
                    [Lowbatterylevel] => 10
                )

        )

)
{"email":"bar@foo.org","password":"password","devices":{"number":"01234567890","type":"CellPhone","config":{"batteryLevel":100,"Lowbatterylevel":10}}}
```